# How to keep a Sinatra cookie value as an integer

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I set the cookie using an integer

```
cookies[:which_link] ||= 0
```

It seems to convert it from an integer to a string, because there are no complaints.  I do a cookies[:which_link].class and it comes back string.

I need to do something like this in my app-

```
cookies[:which_link] -= 1 if params[:pages] == "previous"
```

but will not work, obviously, neither is `to_i` a remedy. Any workarounds for this before I have to consider using one of the Rack options?

In a regular Ruby hash, I input an integer, as a value and it remains so and shows it of the Integer class.

Comment: you could serialize it to json or yaml or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you need, I think `to_i` will work, you'll just need to rewrite your statement a bit. See the following example:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/cookies'

get '/' do
  cookies[:test] ||= 0
  cookies[:test] = cookies[:test].to_i + 1

  "test: #{cookies[:test]}"
end
```

You cannot add a String and a Fixnum but you can convert the String to a Fixnum and then add 1 to it. Then just set the value of that cookie to the new Fixnum which, as you've noted, works.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I'm not sure though how I was adding a String and Fixnum.  What I was originally putting in there was just an integer which somehow gets converted to a string.

Comment: Everything gets serialized by Sinatra to be sent to the client. Try setting a cookie to an Array. You'll find it combined into a String separated by a '&'.

Comment: Gotcha.  I did try an array actually, so yes, I understand now.  ty!